# How to measure correlation between categorical variable?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data

I know that we can use Spearman rho to measure the correlation between numerical variables. But how to measure correlation between categorical variables?

Answer (score 10):

There are way too many measures starting from chi-square based ([phi coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient)) going to less commonly used ([Goodman and Kruskal's lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodman_and_Kruskal%27s_lambda)).

There is a series of four articles [starting here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2281536) on the issue.